Como puedo agregar un apostrofo al inicio de cada numero en una columna de numeros?
Buen dia.
Estoy trabajando con un archivo en formato CSV con python, tengo una columna llamada Contrato con mas de 1000 registros la cual contiene en cada registro 18 digitos que son numeros, busco la manera de agregar un apostrofo al inicio de cada numero para que quedo algo como esto '22316754654654654 no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo con pandas

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

#agregar el apostrofe
dataframe['Contrato'] = dataframe['Contrato'].apply(lambda x: f"'{x}")
Explicacion:
Lo que hacemos es usar el metodo apply que sirve para aplicar una funcion sobre cada elemento (columna,dataframe etc) y en este caso la funcion que se aplica es una lambda que agrega el apostrofe al inicio
